# Countably infinite intersection

Tags: real-analysis

Is it the case that $[a,b]$ is equal to $\cap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (a-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}) $ ? I would have thought it were equal to $(a,b)$ as at $n=\infty$, $(a-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n})$ is equal to $(a,b)$?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ belong to all those intervals, no matter the big is $n$.

Comment: Yes, they are equal. There is no such thing as "at $n=\infty$". You are only indexing by positive integers. Do you think $\infty$ is a positive integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since as you can see $a$ and $b$ belong to the intersection (they belong to every interval).